# Web2py combine index and view controller functions at same url?

Tags: url, controller, web2py

I have a customer index function and a customer view function that lists all the customers and views a single customer respectively.  The urls are like:

`www.example.com/customers`

`www.example.com/customers/view/1`

Which, using the default web2py setup, are mapped to my `index()` and `view()` functions.

This is okay but the "view" part of the url is possibly superfluous.  Instead I want to have stackoverflow-like URLs in my app.  That is, I want my app to behave like

`www.stackoverflow.com/questions` (this shows list of questions)

`www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4` (this shows a single question)

(note there is no "view" in the URL.  Also never mind the slug that stackoverflow tacks on)

So my question is how do I set up web2py to do this?  Do I have to combine the logic for my `index()` and `view()` functions into a single function that detects if there is an ID parameter? Or can I keep them as separate functions and somehow have web2py intelligently map to the proper controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [pattern-based rewrite system](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Pattern-based-system), you could do something like this in /web2py/routes.py:

```
routes_in = (
    ('/myapp/customers/(?P<id>\d+)$', '/myapp/customers/view/\g<id>'),
)

routes_out = (
    ('/myapp/customers/view/(?P<id>\d+)$', '/myapp/customers/\g<id>'),
)
```